# Subtracting hours from timestamp in SAP BO Webi report

Tags: business-objects

Need to subtract a timestamp in a date column in SAP Webi report.

Timestamp is in string for example "`20190302000001`" and there is no proper structure due to information pulled from SQL server. I need to subtract two hours from above timestamp. I have tried relative date function but it doesn't as the timestamp is a string. I tried `To_date()` function but it also doesn't support.

Someone guide me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close. I created a variable called **Timestamp Text**, but you would use your **Timestamp** object instead.

```
[Timestamp Text]="20190302000001"
```

You do need to use the **ToDate()** function, but you need to tell it what format your string is in. Here is a helpful [reference](https://bobjblog.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/web-intelligence-date-formats/) on the various parts of a date/time value.

```
[Timestamp Date]=ToDate([Timestamp Text]; "yyyyMMddhhmmss")
```

Then you use the **RelativeDate()** function to subtract two hours.

```
[Timestamp Minus 2 Hours Date]=RelativeDate([Timestamp Date]; -2; HourPeriod)
```

I am not sure if you need this part, but you can convert it back to the same string format you started with using the **FormatDate()** function.

```
[Timestamp Minus 2 Hours Text]=FormatDate([Timestamp Minus 2 Hours Date]; "yyyyMMddhhmmss")
```

Here are each of the variable values to show the progression. I did have to change the format of the date columns in order to get the time to be displayed.

[image]

Hope that helps you,

Noel